# Stripe: You must request at least one of the following capabilities

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to create a custom Stipe connect account in the test environment.

```
{
  "type": "custom",
  "country": "GB",
  "business_type": "individual",
  "requested_capabilities": null,
  "tos_acceptance": {
    "date": 1565009641,
    "ip": "192.168.1.1"
  },
  "individual": {
    "address": {
      "city": "London",
      "line1": "address1",
      "postal_code": "SW15 5PU"
    },
    "dob": {
      "day": 12,
      "month": 11,
      "year": 1980
    },
    "first_name": "Test",
    "last_name": "Account",
    "phone": "+447911123456",
    "email": "artist1.1@test.com"
  },
  "business_profile": {
    "mcc": 8931,
    "url": "https://website.com"
  }
}
```

But I get the following errors:

`You must request at least one of the following capabilities: card_payments, legacy_payments. ...`

The documentation says requested_capabilities is required for US accounts only.

Anybody knows how to fix the parameters to create the stripe connect account?

Comment: Where you have  `"requested_capabilities": null,"`... You can't have null.  The updated API requires this when making your connect account.  Check the docs on this and you'll see which options you have and what they do.  Or try what Pazinka commented

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you have provided the API version you are using. There were some major changes and it could be that you are sending your params wrong (https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#api-changelog).

You provided the country of the account but not the country of the individual. Depending on the API version, you could pass on the country of the individual (person) behind the account.

Anyways, for a quick test, you can use `legacy_payments` for `requested_capabilities`, that reflects how the things were before. Then you might also see if the country of individual/person is set to GB or it defaults to US.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your API version you are using for Stripe. Take care to check if you have overwritten it using `stripe.setApiVersion('yyyy-mm-dd');`. Check your version and set it explicitly if necessary - here is a link for versioning https://stripe.com/docs/api/versioning

Also, depending on the version, you need to provide a "requested_capabilities" property in the account data. It takes an array of values - for example

```
{...
 'requested_capabilities': ['card_payment', 'transfers'],
...
}
```

Here is a link into the requested capabilities based on your version and country of operation - https://stripe.com/docs/connect/capabilities-overview